# How to number variables in python

Tags: python, variables

I am a beginner and wanted to ask how to assign numbers to your variables. I mean something like player **1**, player **2**, etc..
I mean something like this, but this obviously doesn't work:

```
random_card = cards.pop(randrange(len(cards)))
for x in range(number of players):
    player(x) = random_card
```

(the random card thing is just to simulate what I want to do, my code is different)
What is the best way to assign a number to my variable (player), when I don't know how many players will I have?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Use a dictionary or a list as container.

Comment: Make `player` a `dict()`: `player = dict()`. And then in the loop do `player[x] = random_card`.

Comment: Got it thanks a lot guys! Tried to google my answer but couldn´t find anything related.